# Guide for the performance testing using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I am an SQA Engineer and have just started wanted to start freelancing. From all you experts I just want to have an idea that for performance/load testing specifically for E-com website what test cases should I cover? I am planning to use JMeter what things should I take care of? Any suggestions that you can pour so that I may deliver the BEST.

P.S: Since this is my first project so I would really appreciate and welcome all suggestions and help.

Thanks guyz

Comment: Please edit your post to give more details about what you are needing. Do you want to know where to start? Is there something difficult about the site you need to test that makes it difficult for an experienced tester to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one main "idea": well behaved load test must represent real-life application usage as close as possible. Each JMeter thread (virtual user) need to behave exactly like real user does including:

- actions (login, browser, add project to cart, checkout)
- cookies (via [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager))
- headers (via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager))
- embedded resources (via [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)) and cache (via [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager))
- think times (via [Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers))

Assuming all above you need to think how users will be accessing your application (unauthenticated users searching and crawling, authenticated users making purchases, etc.) and conduct workload accordingly.

Check out [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html) JMeter User Manual entry to get started. You can also consider attending free [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/jmeter-tutorial) to get ramped up on JMeter in few hours.

Comment: Thanks. ok, so what should be the plan how should it be started according to you?

Let say if we talk about checkout what would you suggest. How to do this?

Comment: Given you managed to master both JMeter User Manual and JMeter Academy in 16 minutes you should know JMeter better than me so I'm afraid I cannot help further

Comment: ohh that's ok don't be afraid but anyways thanks for sharing the links.